# How to implement a dynamic calendar in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, lan

In my current project, I need a calendar that would store manufacturing schedules dynamically (from a MySQL Workbench database). For example, product A would be manufactured today from 8 A.M.- 12 NN then product B is scheduled to be manufactured at 12 NN - 5 P.M. When clicked, it would display the information regarding the schedule (product to be manufactured, quantity, etc.)

I have tried to look online for the solutions but I failed. The results that were provided was primarily web-based (asp.net and php) calendar. My project wasn't web-based, it was LAN-based. If it helps, I am using Visual Studio 2015 
with .NET framework 4.5.2

Any ideas and suggestions would help.

Comment: I think you got some confusion in understanding web app concept. Web based apps can also run on LAN/Intranet. There is not need to connect them to internet. Just you need to setup local web server and database (on simple PC) and then host your calendar app on that to use within LAN.

Comment: Anyway, what is your question?

Comment: I suggest that if you got any related solutions in your search results, you can consider them.